# How do I redirecting user from one web page to another 2 times in javascript after clicking on submit button?

Tags: javascript

So, I was wondering how to do it as I really need help with it and hopefully, I can solve these codes

```
function redirect() {
   window.location.replace("Contact.html");
   return false;
}


<form  onsubmit="return redirect()">
<input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
```

Comment: function redirect() {
  window.location.replace("Contact.html");
  return false;
}

Comment: <form  onsubmit="return redirect()">
<input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the code. Don't post comments for that.

Comment: Sorry my codes are a little messed up as I couldn't put in the codes, any form of help will be deeply appreciated, Thanks

Comment: Thanks nicael for the help